# Error creating args array of jvalues for NewObjectA() function - JNI Invocation API

Tags: java, c++, compiler-errors, java-native-interface, invocation

I'm trying to create a jobject in C++ by calling the NewObjectA() function using the JNI invocation API. However, I am unsure how I should pass arguments into the constructor. The JNI API documentation states:

> jobject NewObjectA(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz,jmethodID methodID, const
>   jvalue *args);
>
> NewObjectA
>
> Programmers place all arguments that are to be passed to the
>   constructor in an args array of jvalues that immediately follows the
>   methodID argument. NewObjectA() accepts the arguments in this array,
>   and, in turn, passes them to the Java method that the programmer
>   wishes to invoke.

In my case the constructor requires two java strings passed to it. I have therefore tried the following:

```
jclass jcls_File = env->FindClass("java/io/File");
jmethodID  File_constructor = env->GetMethodID(jcls_File, "<init>","(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V");
jstring home = ctojstring(env,"/home/workspace");
jstring filename = ctojstring(env,"mydatafile");
jvalue FileLocationParams[] = {home,filename};  // COMPILE ERROR HERE.
jobject MyDataFile = env->NewObjectA(jcls_File, File_constructor,FileLocationParams);
```

Where ctojstring is just the following function:

```
jstring ctojstring(JNIEnv *env,std::string mystring){
    return env->NewStringUTF(mystring.c_str());
}
```

But when I try to compile I get the following error in Eclipse:

**error: invalid conversion from ‘jstring {aka _jstring*}’ to ‘jboolean {aka unsigned char}’ [-fpermissive]**

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jvalue` is of type union.

And it is declared as follows:

```
typedef union jvalue { 
    jboolean z; 
    jbyte    b; 
    jchar    c; 
    jshort   s; 
    jint     i; 
    jlong    j; 
    jfloat   f; 
    jdouble  d; 
    jobject  l; 
} jvalue;
```

If you want to assign `jstring` to `jvalue` you could do as below.

```
jvalue FileLocationParams[2];
FileLocationParams[0].l = home;
FileLocationParams[1].l = filename;
```

Instead of

```
jvalue FileLocationParams[] = {home,filename};  // COMPILE ERROR HERE.
```

As it will try to assign `home` and `filename` to first member of `jvalue` which is `jboolean z`.

Comment: This makes perfect sense now. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a more elegant way of assigning the jvalues to the array elements (in case I want to pass a much longer list of arguments to the constructors).?

Comment: @Ddor Using loop? If you have longer list of arguments as array.